# Error DescribeData: Method areaFieldName does not exist

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.6, esri-production-mapping

I am trying to Increase Polygon Area using "Increase Polygon Area" Tool in the "Production Mapping Tools" in ArcGIS 10.6, which is returning the following error: DescribeData: Method areaFieldName does not exist.

I added a new field and calculated (Calculate geometry) area and set the projection, but no luck so far.

Is there any idea how can this error be fixed?

[image]

Comment: Your input features are in a projected coordinate system right? Is this part of a script? Could you add the code?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to contain the error message as ASCII text. This would make the message both legible on all devices and searchable for others with the same problem.